# i want to use a specific symbol masking in an html text field using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, masking

I want to use a particular masking on a text field in which the symbol will be on the right of the field. Mostly we see in bootstrap, but i need it without bootstrap and using jquery. Although it is bit difficult to explain but i can attach an image of my requirement.
[image]

Comment: So, you want an input, with a % sign (or something you can define for yourself) placed behind it?

Comment: It can be statically defined, its a special kind of masking for any field, we see in bootstrap, but it is difficult to find without bootstrap. I have shown in pic attached, i need the same thing.

Comment: So, you're not 'masking' as such, but you want to add a picture or text to, or beside, an `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to use jquery to do something like this. Isn't a simple css class with some markup enough?

Something like this:

```
background: url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/System/Fugue/edit%20percent.png) right no-repeat;
padding-right: 15px;
```

I made you a little jsfiddle to show how I would do it. Sure it isn't as fancy but you could add additional css styling to spice it up.

http://jsfiddle.net/DtkQF/